# Is it possible to get Safari to use HTTP Conditional Get for the first document?

Tags: http, http-headers, safari, etag

I'm trying to add HTTP Conditional Get functionality to the first page of a mobile site. However, what I'm seeing is making me think that Safari simply doesn't support HTTP Conditional Get for the first document it loads.

I tested this by making a new Rails 3.2.13 application, with one action that looks like this:

```
def index
  last_modified = Date.today
  etag_obj = "something something"
  fresh_when last_modified: last_modified, etag: etag_obj, public: false
end
```

The request headers contain both an Etag and Last-Modified, as expected:

```
[cache_test]$ curl -I http://localhost:5000/test
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Etag: "79b547467286b3e20fad13f73fc1bf78"
Last-Modified: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=Edge
X-Request-Id: 8ace0b71533b2bc036bd84b12289cda6
X-Runtime: 0.012269
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2012-04-20)
Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 21:06:49 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Set-Cookie: _cache_test_session=BAh7B0kiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJTM0NWRjNDgyZGQwNWJmMGZkNmIzNmY4NjVmNWEzMDkwBjsAVEkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMTlYK0VrMERGdEsvOVlzbVJ5N1FPQlZXVDRwak9zQ3QzS3ZXZ1pvbnJocjg9BjsARg%3D%3D--0902ae8a505527bd49d969753ddf1d2bd4c716eb; path=/; HttpOnly
```

On Firefox 20.0 and Chrome 26.0.1410.65 this acts like I expect: On the second load, the browser sends If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match in the request, and receives a 304 Not Modified.

However, it's not doing this on Safari. On Safari it sends neither If-Modified-Since nor If-None-Match, and as you'd expect, it then fully reloads the page from the server. I am seeing this on Safari 6.0.3 on my MacBook Pro, Safari in the iOS Simulator using an iPhone with iOS 6.1, and on an iPad Mini with iOS 6.1.3.

And what's really strange about this is that Safari clearly supports Conditional Get for subsequent requests (CSS, JS, images, etc) -- I can see them clearly after the main HTML page comes through. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to get Safari to make a Conditional Get request for the first document.

So, I guess my question is two parts:

1. Am I missing something obvious? Because it actually seems a little crazy that Safari would act this way by design. But maybe I'm expecting too much from Apple here.
2. If I'm not missing something obvious, does anybody know of any workarounds?